# Label hide very slow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Code create label and button that hide the label. But when run code and press button to hide label, it take long time to hide. Please help me, how to fix this problem?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 300, height: 30))
    label.text = "Hey"
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let switchButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 500, width: 300, height: 40))
    switchButton.setTitle("Change label text", for: .normal)
    switchButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    switchButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    switchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hide), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(switchButton)
    }

    @IBAction func hide(_ sender: Any){
        self.label.isHidden = true
        print("check")
    }
}
```

Slow update the UI

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? it should be instant if you run this on main thread.

Comment: It take 15 sec before label disappear. In IBAction, I also put print("check") to see that  button have been pressed and activate code that text "check" show up but label do not instant disappear (delay for 15 sec).

Comment: @Yoshi, Have you enabled `debug slow animations` option on the simulator ?

Comment: In simulator window bar -> Debug -> Uncheck Slow Animations

Comment: have you tried `setNeedsDisplay()` on the label?  That will indicate the system it should be redrawn the next cycle.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay

Comment: @pkc456 simulator already uncheck for slow animation.

Comment: @Joshua Smith I did not ever try for setNeedsDisplay(). I try both self.label.setNeedsDisplay() and self.view.setNeedsDisplay() but label still do not immediate disappear